# Https Test Script Recorder is not generating results in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load

I try to record a simple test in my Firefox browser with Jmeter and Https Test Script Recorder. I did like in manual from the Internet, configure manual proxy in Firefox with port 8080 (tried different ports) and the same port in Jmeter, but after recording I cannot see any results in my Jmeter. Can you advise me how to fix this issue?
[image]

I tried to test a simple script in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to click "Start" button in order to start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, otherwise Firefox will tell you that the proxy server is down

   [image]
2. You need to configure Firefox to use JMeter as the proxy:

   [image]
3. You need to allow Firefox to use proxies for local addresses:

   [image]
4. You need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate into Firefox, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

   [image]

   make sure that it's not expired and you allow it to be trusted to identify websites

   [image]

Assuming all above you should be able to record the traffic from Firefox using JMeter successfully.

---

Alternatively you can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.